# Java regular expression to validate and extract some values

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract all three parts of the following string in Java

```
MS-1990-10
```

1. The first part should always be 2 letters (`A-Z`)
2. The second part should always be a year
3. The third part should always be a number

Does anyone know how can I do that using Java's regular expressions?

Comment: If you know this is what the string will always look like, can't you just split it by `-` and get the 3 parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using java's pattern matcher and group syntax:

```
    Pattern datePatt = Pattern.compile("([A-Z]{2})-(\\d{4})-(\\d{2})");
    Matcher m = datePatt.matcher("MS-1990-10");
    if (m.matches()) {
        String g1 = m.group(1);
        String g2 = m.group(2);
        String g3 = m.group(3);
    }
```

Comment: How can i change the last part for any number?

Comment: You could use `\\d+`, which means `\\d one or more times`.

Comment: `\\d` is a digit and `{2}` is the number of them you expect. You could make it `\\d{1,10}` if you know the number will be between 1 and 10 digits, for instance. Or you could just say `\\d+`.

Comment: Also, be aware that the `(\\d{4})` will match any 4 digit number which would include `0052` but it would not include `123`.

Comment: True! Perhaps better to use something like `(19|20)\\d{2}` for the year.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to get all 3 parts with a regex:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) {

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([A-Z]{2})-(\\d{4})-(\\d{2})");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("MS-1990-10");
        m.matches();
        for (int i = 1; i <= m.groupCount(); i++)
            System.out.println(m.group(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Never call `matches()` or `find()` without checking its return value.  If the match fails, you won't know it until `m.group(i)` throws an exception.

Comment: @AlanMoore The match is guaranteed to work. It is the same as not needing to catch every possible exception for every line in the code that can throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)'s group so you can get the patterns that actually matched.
In `Matcher`, the matches inside parenthesis will be captured and can be retrieved via the `group()` method. To use parenthesis without capturing the matches, use the non-capturing parenthesis `(?:xxx)`.

See also [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String[] lines = { "MS-1990-10", "AA-999-12332", "ZZ-001-000" };

    for (String str : lines) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parse(str)));
    }
}

private static String[] parse(String str) {
    String regex = "";
    regex = regex + "([A-Z]{2})";
    regex = regex + "[-]";
    // regex = regex + "([^0][0-9]+)"; // any year, no leading zero
    regex = regex + "([12]{1}[0-9]{3})"; // 1000 - 2999
    regex = regex + "[-]";
    regex = regex + "([0-9]+)";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    if (!matcher.matches()) {
        return null;
    }

    String[] tokens = new String[3];
    tokens[0] = matcher.group(1);
    tokens[1] = matcher.group(2);
    tokens[2] = matcher.group(3);
    return tokens;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String rule = "^[A-Z]{2}-[1-9][0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(rule);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
```

regular matches year between 1000 ~ 9999, u can update as u really need.